# How to deploy machine learning model to predict with multiple feature data

Tags: python, machine-learning, predict

I have a trained machine learning model need to be deploy. It is trained with mutltiple features but how to use that model to predict with multiple feature data.
for example i need to use these feature data to predict the result

```
input = [46.8,11,7,0.686563,6.540829e-08,1.133174e-09]
```

i used following code but itseems predict() is working only for single feature data.

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model = joblib.load('SVM_LINEAR')
model.predict([46.8,11,7,0.686563,6.540829e-08,1.133174e-09])
```

Comment: What is the result? Do you get any error? And, if you have *trained* the model with only a single feature, you can certainly not deploy it with multiple ones...

Comment: How did you train the model? Can you elaborate a little bit more about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make a numpy array of features and then pass it inside `model.predict` i.e.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model = joblib.load('SVM_LINEAR')
model.predict(np.asarray([46.8,11,7,0.686563,6.540829e-08,1.133174e-09]))
```

or you can try this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.externals import joblib
model = joblib.load('SVM_LINEAR')
model.predict([[46.8,11,7,0.686563,6.540829e-08,1.133174e-09]])
```